Kant acknowledges physical needs as well as moral law, but has he adequately explained why one should win out over the other?
Theorem II, Book 1, of the Critique of Practical Reason acknowledges finite beings, as part of physical nature, and that they have desires and needs, specifically a need to be happy.  But the Critique also champions this other ideal force of moral law.  If we only acted on one of these drives--morality or happiness--to the exclusion of all else, we would have a problem.  It seems clear that human survival requires balancing them.
What does Kant say about achieving a proper balance?
Drawn from 5:22-23 from Critique of Practical Reason.

Can you reference any paragraph that Kant claimed assertively they have to conflict?...

Kant was no balancer, he despised any form of utilitarianism. So he is very clear, if needs and desires do conflict with moral law then moral law wins come what may, see murderer at the door for a striking example. If this seems harsh recall the Latin maxim fiat iustitia, et pereat mundus, "let the world die but justice prevail", so Kant had company. Of course, the moral law itself does take into account human needs and desires in a general way, so many 'conflicts' are only apparent, but not because of any "balancing".

I guess I think of a need for balance in this sense--if one does not take care of basic physical needs, e.g., desire stemming from hunger or thirst, then there s no room for moral behavior because then there would be no rational beings alive to act morally.  Less dramatic, but nevertheless necessary, might be psychological needs.  Happiness, at least a certain measure of it, may actually be necessary to carry out those maxims that are purely rational and independent of feeling.

To understand how Kant addresses the balance between the drive for happiness and the moral law in the "Critique of Practical Reason," especially in relation to passages from 5:22-23, we need to delve into his discussions on the nature of human beings as finite rational agents and the conditions for the summum bonum (the highest good).
First of all, however, I should say that the best short answer would be negative. As Conifold said in the comments: "Kant was no balancer, he despised any form of utilitarianism.". That's what I think too. I think, however, that if you ask Kant directly this, he would never admit that. So I tried to write what I think Kant would reply.
Key Points from 5:22-23 in the "Critique of Practical Reason":

Dual Drives of Human Nature:

Physical Nature: As part of the physical world, humans have desires and needs, including the natural inclination to seek happiness.

Moral Law: As rational beings, humans are also subject to the moral law, which demands that actions be performed out of duty and respect for the moral law itself, not merely to achieve happiness.

Kant argues that morality is the supreme good and that happiness is its second element, which must be morally conditioned. This implies that true happiness can only be achieved through moral virtue:

"Morality is the supreme good (as the first condition of the summum bonum), while happiness constitutes its second element, but only in such a way that it is the morally conditioned, but necessary consequence of the former"




The Concept of the Summum Bonum:

Kant introduces the concept of the summum bonum, which combines both moral virtue and happiness. This ideal state is where moral virtue leads to happiness, aligning the two drives harmoniously.

The summum bonum represents the highest good, combining both moral virtue and happiness. Kant insists that practical reason commands us to strive for this ideal:

"Only with this subordination is the summum bonum the whole object of pure practical reason, which must necessarily conceive it as possible, since it commands us to contribute to the utmost of our power to its realization"




Role of Moral Law and Happiness:

Primacy of Moral Law: Kant argues that moral law must be the supreme guiding principle. Happiness should not be the primary aim but a consequence of acting morally.
Subordination of Happiness: Happiness is considered the second element of the summum bonum, conditioned by moral virtue. It cannot be pursued directly as the ultimate goal; rather, it follows from adherence to the moral law.



Achieving a Proper Balance According to Kant:

Moral Worth and Happiness:

Moral worth arises from actions performed out of respect for the moral law. Kant insists that actions motivated solely by the pursuit of happiness lack true moral value.

Happiness, in Kant's framework, is to be understood as a state that rational beings may hope for as a result of living in accordance with moral principles.

Kant emphasizes that while morality must guide our actions, the pursuit of happiness is also important but must be aligned with moral principles:



"It may even in certain respects be a duty to provide for happiness; partly, because it contains means for the fulfilment of our duty; partly, because the absence of it (e.g., poverty) implies temptations to transgress our duty. But it can never be an immediate duty to promote our happiness, still less can it be the principle of all duty"


Practical Reason and the Summum Bonum:

Practical reason demands that we strive for the summum bonum. This entails that we act morally while also hoping for happiness as a deserved outcome.
The pursuit of the summum bonum involves working towards a world where moral virtue leads to happiness. This necessitates a belief in a harmonious order that rewards moral behavior with happiness.


The Necessity of Belief in God and Immortality:

Kant postulates the existence of God and the immortality of the soul as necessary conditions for the realization of the summum bonum. This belief helps reconcile the demands of moral law with the hope for happiness.
In a world governed by moral laws, it is reasonable to believe that a just and benevolent God ensures that virtue and happiness ultimately coincide, even if not fully realized in this life.




Kant postulates the existence of God and immortality as necessary for the realization of the summum bonum. These postulates help reconcile the pursuit of moral virtue with the hope for proportional happiness:

"In the practical problem of pure reason, i.e., the necessary pursuit of the summum bonum, such a connection is postulated as necessary: we ought to endeavour to promote the summum bonum, which, therefore, must be possible. Accordingly, the existence of a cause of all nature, distinct from nature itself and containing the principle of this connection, namely, of the exact harmony of happiness with morality, is also postulated".



